# call a methods of a class without using NEW keyword inside other class node js

Tags: javascript, class, oop, inheritance, delegation

I want to access Main class methods to another Person class without creating a new instance Is it possible??
Can we access it without creating an instance of a class

> let myInstance = new Person();

```
 class Main {
      constructor(args) {
        this.hooks = [];
      }
      add_hooks(name, func) {
        if (!this.hooks[name]) this.hooks[name] = [];
        this.hooks[name].push(func);
      }
      call_hooks(name, ...params) {
        if (this.hooks[name]) this.hooks[name].forEach((func) => func(...params));
      }
    }
```

other class Person how to access without using **new** keyword

```
const Main = require("./main.js");
class Person {
  exec() {
    const action =  Main();
    action.add_hook("jump", console.log.bind(console, "this will log "));
  }
}
```

Comment: At SO it is considered to be a nice gesture from the one who got help, to provide some feedback and/or vote on answers and/or accept the answer which was the most helpful in solving the OP's problem.

Comment: From all the provided solutions/approaches are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no big magic to it. Since the OP just wants to reuse prototypal `Main` methods, one is going to explicitly delegate the method/s of interest which was/were provided/accessed before via `Main.prototype` ...

```js
class Main {
  constructor(args) {
    this.hooks = {};
  }
  add_hooks(name, func) {
    if (!this.hooks[name]) {
      this.hooks[name] = [];
    }
    this.hooks[name].push(func);
  }
  call_hooks(name, ...params) {
    if (this.hooks[name]) {
      this.hooks[name].forEach(func => func(...params));
    }
  }
}

// const Main = require("./main.js");

class Person {

  // // ... either add `hooks` as public property at instantiation time ...
  // hooks = {};

  exec() {
    const ref = Main.prototype;
    ref.add_hooks.call(this, "jump", console.log.bind(console, "this will log"));
  }
}

// ... or add `hooks` via additional glue code ...
function createPersonWithHooksAndExecute() {
  const type = new Person();

  type.hooks = {};
  type.exec();

  return type;
}
const someone = createPersonWithHooksAndExecute();
console.log({ someone });

// this will log
Main.prototype.call_hooks.call(someone, "jump");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not planning on instantiating the object, and you don't care about having multiple instances with each having their own state, you don't need a class.

Just create individual functions, or export an object.

```js
const hooks = [];

export function add_hooks(name, func) {
  if (!hooks[name]) hooks[name] = [];
  hooks[name].push(func);
}

export function call_hooks(name, ...params) {
  if (!hooks[name]) return;
  for (const func of this.hooks[name]) {
    func(...params);
  }
}
```

It's possible too to do this with static methods, and that would be the likely answer if you write Java where everything *has* to be a class, but I wouldn't recommended it in Javascript.

Comment: In the existing code, I need to access the Parent class methods in another class when ever I am accessing it using 
 let myInstance = new Person();
It is updating its current state

Comment: @Kainat then just don't use `super`, but directly refer to the functions that you want to use from the other class.

Comment: @Alnitak you probably mean the opposite?